# What is the equivalent of Android's MediaCodec.queueInputBuffer() in iOS?

Tags: ios, core-audio, android-mediacodec, audioqueue

I trying to play Audio with specific PTS(=DTS. decoding time stamp.)

So, I have tried to use AudioQueueEnqueueBufferWithParameters() with the inStartTime parameter to delay the start of playing each buffer, But that is not working.

I know that in android, MediaCodec class's queueInputBuffer method can play audio data with PTS. (see description : [MediaCodec.queueInputBuffer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#queueInputBuffer(int,%20int,%20int,%20long,%20int)))

I want to find the API in iOS that like MediaCodec's queueInputBuffer method.

If there is no the API in iOS,
How can I play each audio buffer with specific PTS ?